# Background javascript animation using CSS webkit and Slick

Tags: javascript, css, animation, webkit, slick.js

I have a slider which changes the background depending on the current image. The problem is the transition between the backgrounds is non-existent. I don't want to use the "transition" propriety as it doesn't offer the exact animation that I want.

**Codepen : https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/LYNGNEZ**

**The script to change the background :**

```
$(function(){


var imgUrl = {
    "image1" : "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/184795.jpg",
    "image2" : "https://images2.alphacoders.com/774/774269.jpg",
    "image3" : "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2020010.jpg",
};


 
$('.slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 800,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 8000,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
});
  
changeBg(imgUrl)
$('#slider').on('afterChange', ".slider", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    changeBg(imgUrl)
});  

function changeBg(imgUrl) {
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + imgUrl[$(".slick-track div.slick-slide.slick-active").attr("class").split(" ")[0]] + ")");

}
});
```

**Script of the wanted animation :**

```
.fade-in-right {
            -webkit-animation: fade-in-right 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
                    animation: fade-in-right 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
        }
    * Generated by Animista on 2020-8-12 15:20:11
    * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
    * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
    * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
    * ---------------------------------------------- */

    /**
    * ----------------------------------------
    * animation fade-in-right
    * ----------------------------------------
    */
    @-webkit-keyframes fade-in-right {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
                transform: translateX(50px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    }
    @keyframes fade-in-right {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50px);
                transform: translateX(50px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                transform: translateX(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    }
```

Comment: writing that css transitions are not what you are looking for doesn't guess what you are looking to do.

Comment: In what way does using `transition` differ from your desired result?

Comment: @showdev My desired result is a Fade In Right, not a simple harsh fade. I'm trying to replicate this and I already achieved the slider, need to do so for the background like this https://youtu.be/fd-OtagLfu8.

Comment: @MisterJojo The background transitions in the beginning of this video https://youtu.be/fd-OtagLfu8

Comment: I believe that I need to add CSS animation inside the Javascript code so each image will be shown with the effect, but how ?